# Refinement Panel Web Part for Anonymous Users

Tags: search, search-results, refinement-panel

I´m working with the core results web part, executing the search using elevated privileges for anonymous users to show all the results, but the refinement panel doesn’t seem to work, Is it possible to run the refinement panel using elevated privileges?

Answer (score 1):

If done the correct way, the refinement web part acts according to the xml returned by the core search results web part... [Look at this blog for more info.](http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2012/04/elevated-search-results-sharepoint-2010.html) This quote is from the Kjell:

> "The nice thing about using the built-in query manager this way, rather than running your own KeywordQuery and providing your own result XML local to the custom web-part instance, is that the shared QueryManager's Location object will get its Result XML document populated. This is important for the correct behavior for the other search web-parts on the page using the same QueryNumber / UserQuery, such as the paging and refiners web-parts."

Hope this helps!